# Primitive roots modulo $p^k$

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to follow an example. It states that if $p$ is an odd prime such that $p \equiv 1 \hspace{1mm} (\mathrm{mod} \hspace{1mm} 4)$, and $r$ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$, then $$r^{\frac{p-1}{2}p^{k-1}} \equiv -1 \hspace{1mm} (\mathrm{mod} \hspace{1mm} p^k). $$

I'm confused about this. First of all, if $p \equiv 1 \hspace{1mm} (\mathrm{mod} \hspace{1mm} 4)$, then $p-1 = 4t$ and $r^{(p-1)/2} = r^{2t}$ and then $r^{\frac{p-1}{2}p^{k-1}} = (r^{p^{k-1}})^{2t} $ and I don't see how that could be a negative number.

Meanwhile, $r$ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$, so $r^{\phi(p^k)} \equiv 1 \hspace{1mm} (\mathrm{mod} \hspace{1mm} p^k) $ and $\phi(p^k) = p^k - p^{k-1}$, so shouldn't we have $r^{\frac{p-1}{2}p^{k-1}} = r^{\frac{p^k - p^{k-1}}{2}} = r^{\phi(p^k)/2} \equiv  (1)^{1/2} = 1 $?

(Note that $\phi(n)$ is Euler's phi-function.)

Comment: Note:  $-1$ could also be a square root of $1$

Comment: "I don't see how that could be a negative number" It isn't a negative number, but it is **congruent** to a negative number modulo $p^k$, just as all integers are.

Comment: Yep, I see that now, I was confused. :) @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$r$ is  a *primitive* root mod $p^k$.
This means that $r^{\phi(p^k)}\equiv 1 \bmod p^k$, and this is the least exponent for which this equality holds (so notably $r^{\phi(p^k)/2}\not\equiv 1\bmod p^k$).
One must therefore have that $r^{\phi(p^k)/2}\equiv -1\bmod p^k$, as desired.

Comment: Well it is because the unit group is cyclic that there are (at most) two square roots of $1$ (modulo $8$ there are 4 square roots)